# Parsing Mixedt CSV-File with TextFieldParser

Tags: c#, parsing, csv

Hello I have a problem to parse a CSV-file. The CSV-File is Delimited with | character . So far so good. But only one field is enclosed with the " char.
For example

```
field1|field2|"field3"|field4
```

When I set the

> HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes

to true the i will become a exception otherwise the parsing of the CSV-File goes wrong. Can you help me here.

Comment: see my answer, tested code for your input, works as expected

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a culture, where '|' is csv separator...

All in all,

```
var line = "field1|field2|\"field3\"|field4";
var pattern = string.Format("{0}(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", Regex.Escape("|")); 
//{0} in pattern is CSV separator. To get current use System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator
var splitted = Regex.Split(line, pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

foreach (var s in splitted)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
field1
field2
"field3"
field4
```

Pattern is designed to split a single line from a CSV file using specified separator characters. Includes handling of quotes, etc.
Hope that will help you.

Answer (score -2):

Quick and dirty: You could consider stripping the document of all uses of " beforehand.

```
string path = "c:\\test.txt";
string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
s = s.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, s, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
```

Edit 1:
This method works for number columns or string columns containing only one word, but could break your csv structure in other cases (e.g. field stores html content) - be aware of possible side effects.

Comment: Is not the solution. In Field3  there is HTML code which includes "

Comment: WAT? Are you sure you are aware about quotes role in CSV?

Comment: @taras.roshko: yes I am. 
I agree - not suitable for html content. 

I think the down vote is not fair. This simple method has been sufficient for me on multiple occasions.

Comment: It's good for eliminating " symbols from string, but in case of CSV it can (and will in OP's case) break CSV file structure, which is not desired result. Somewhat simplified CSV structure explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values